# xenserver ISO library

Tags: xen, iso

I am trying to create ISO repository with this guide: http://kb.softescu.ro/server-administration/linux-server-administration/how-to-create-a-local-iso-storage-repository-on-citrix-xenserver/ ("Inside the main partition" chapter).
Problem is that I have 3 xenservers connected into pool(let's say xen1, xen2 and xen3). And if I create ISO library on xen3, it appears on xen1(pool master) and I cannot attach images from this repository to VMs that are on xen3, because xen3 does not see this repository.
Am I doing smth wrong or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even your link URI says "how to create a *local* iso storage ...", so the guide you are following is creating just that - a local storage.  However, your question is re: creating a pool storage (which is visible from multiple pool members).  To achieve that you need to attach your ISO library via one of the supported methods: NFS, iSCSI, or HBA.

In other words, you need to host your library somewhere (e.g. in a VM on your pool), then export the library via NFS inside the VM, then mount that NFS share as a storage in Xen.

Comment: Jep, I am trying to create a local storage, but I am creating it on xen3, but it appears on xen1 and is not accessible on xen3.

Comment: Well, then it seems that you didn't specify the host-uuid argument to your "xe sr-create" command and it used the pool master by default.

Comment: I've tried adding device-config:host-uuid= to command, but ISO repository still neing created on xen1

Comment: @erizo, try "xe sr-create host-uuid=...", there is nowhere I said that it's a device-config sub option.